Server can't ping Client, Client can't ping server, Switch between them can ping both
Ok I've been pulling my hair out over this for a while. I have a Windows Server 2016 machine that is running a database off it and all devices on the network can talk to the server except 2 of them. The Server is also the DNS and DC and is static set to 192.168.0.20, it can talk to the switch at 192.168.0.3 but can't talk to the 2 clients at .10 and .183 on the same subnet.
Here's the weird thing. The .183 client is DHCP and the server is also the DHCP server. So how is it getting the IP? Another weird thing is when I ping the server's hostname from the clients, it responds with ipv6.
The clients and the server can talk to the switch between them and vice versa and the server can talk to all other clients. What the heck is going on?
Here's the setup:
Server <----> Switch <----> Client Devices
If you need more info just ask.
So the 2 clients I'm having trouble with are connected via ethernet and ping didn't work. I got "Destination Host Unreachable" so I added both clients to the server's Mac Table statically. Now when I ping them I get "Request timed out". Did the same thing on the clients but it still didn't work.
When I tried to add the clients to the domain, it said the DNS SRV record didn't exist, but it does.
I tried static routing the clients to the server and vice versa but that did nothing.
Turning off firewall did nothing.
Here's the ping results:
enter image description here

There's probably something specific that you missed that makes sense, esp. the ICMP doesn't work when everyone else seems to WFM.
You should put the output of the PING command into the question... for starters.

Have you tried IPv6? What about when you connect one of the devices without the switch?

I put the output of the Ping into the description. As for IPv6, it appears to work when I Ping the server from the host, as I said above.
